# PHP login, index redirects to password input when checking credentials

Tags: php, html, security, dynamic, authentication

I am taking my first steps into `php` and I have come across this unsolvable for me problem. I am trying to create a website which uses a simply `MySQL` database to identify some credentials given by the visitor. Please note that at this point *I am not really interested about the overall security of the website*. Now to the problem:

Suppose I have 3 files.
In file `main_login.php` the form that the user must use to enter the website is stored, which is calling `checklogin.php`:

```
<form name="form1" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
```

In `checklogin.php` I am checking whether the input (Name and Password) given by the user is contained on the database and if that's correct I am redirecting him to `index.php`:

```
// More unrelated php here....
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
// If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1)
{   
   // Register $username, $password and redirect to file "index.php"
   $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
   $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
   header("location:index.php");
}
else 
{
   echo "Wrong username or password";
}
```

Finally in `index.php` I am checking if the `$_SESSION[username]' is defined, otherwise I redirect the user to the main_login.php.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['username']))
    {
        header("location: main_login.php");
    }
?>

// HTML code here...
```

The **problem** now: Perhaps I have put too many hours into this and I can't think clearly but whenever I input the correct password and username I am always redirected to main_login.php, unlike when I put the wrong credentials. Anyone likely to solve this?

Comment: Do you have a session_start(); before you set the $_SESSION['username']? Why do you store the password? Please use exit(); right after you set the location header. Using the old mysql extensions is discouraged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you haven't started the session when you are setting the session variables on the checklogin page. This means that `$_SESSION['username']` will not be set once they get redirected to the index page.

Comment: It can't be so easy. Thanks!

Comment: oh I though the session_start is just somewhere in `// More unrelated php here...`

Comment: @itsid But it wouldn't be among that, since this is _related_ PHP. ;-)

Comment: @Wiseguy well it IS but do you expect a newbie to know that?

Comment: @itsid Doesn't matter, really. It's an easy enough thing for even the most experienced user to overlook. I was just being goofy.

Answer (score 0):

session_start() creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.

if you don't hava a session-cookie and because you have no post or gets there session_start starts a FRESH session, and thus clears username and password just add SID to your redirects to be safe otherwise you'll be redirected to index and directly to login again.

```
header("location:index.php".SID); //should fix the missing sessioncookie
```

Answer (score 0):

`session_start()` at the top of your Script before any output.

your session is not initalized, therefore you cannot manipulate the session variables.